# Handle html resources while building an Angular4 library

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I have the following src project structure in Angular4:

```
src/
   my-component.ts
   my-component.html
```

When building the library I run `tsc -p .` and a dist is created with the compiled js. The library works well but the html is not copied in the dist folder. What am I doing wrong?

(The same happens when I run npm publish. The library is compiled, pushed but without the html file.)

I add here the scripts of my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "lint": "tslint --type-check --project tsconfig.json src/**/*.ts",
    "test": "tsc && karma start",
    "prepublish": "tsc",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  }
```

EDIT:

I know that tsc cannot move resource. It just compiles Typescript. So, is it necessary to use Gulp or something like this?

Comment: Please take a look at this [yeoman generator to create an Angular 2 library](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library).

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I already used this YO generator. The point is that html files are not handled and there is no documentation for that.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I found this issue though https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/15, I'll try this solutions!

Comment: `tsc` only transpiles typescript to javascript. No HTML involved. That work is done by the angular compiler. Are you using angular-cli? angular-seed? or any other quick-start project? are you using webpack, rollup or systemjs for bundling ?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam I'm using AngularCLI. Unfortunately, I found out that components in dependencies should use template and not templateUrl (I checked the Angular2 Material project).

Comment: so you are building an angular npm package tobe consumed by an angular app? a component library basically ?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam exactly!

Comment: well then why not expose the source ts files, you really done need to transpile your ts into js. the parent project (that will include the library) will do that for you. Your library does not even need to be using angular-cli. I worked on a library project and I exposed the source TS since I know all my consumers were using TS and will do the transpiling anyway. It also helps in tree-shaking and aot.